# TensorFlow: More than one thread in shuffle_batch for single sample files

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand the significance of using `num_threads>1` in `tf.train.shuffle_batch` connected to `tf.WholeFileReader` reading image files (each file contains a single data sample). Will setting `num_threads>1` make any difference in such case compared to `num_threads=1`? What is the mechanics of the file and batch queues in such case?

Answer (score 0):

A short answer: probably it will make the execution faster. Here is some authoritative explanation from the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#batching):

> single reader via the `tf.train.shuffle_batch` with `num_threads` bigger
>   than 1. This will make it read from a single file at the same time
>   (but faster than with 1 thread), instead of N files at once. This can
>   be important:
>
> - If you have more reading threads than input files, to avoid the risk
>     that you will have two threads reading the same example from the same
>     file near each other.
> - Or if reading N files in parallel causes too
>     many disk seeks. How many threads do you need?
>
> the
>   `tf.train.shuffle_batch*` functions add a summary to the graph that
>   indicates how full the example queue is. If you have enough reading
>   threads, that summary will stay above zero.

Comment: Thanks, but I saw the guide before asking the question, and to me it potentially says the opposite. The problem is, it's not very clearly written. Can you explain the mechanics of the queues that would demonstrate why it would be faster?